# add a specific column to all tables that exist in an oracle database

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to achieve this? Something like

```
alter table
'all_tables' add(newcol varchar2(20));
```

is this possible?

Comment: are you working on plsql ? if yes you can do it Dynamicall.. ill write it for you .. but why you want to do such ? maybe there are tables you dont need to add .. keep in touch you dont want to add thoses tables to system or view tables

Comment: What about using `cursor`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run the following in sqlplus or sql developer, and then run the output from the query

```
select 'alter table ' || table_name || ' add (newcol varchar2(20));'
from user_tables
```

Answer (score 3):

Or directly execute the alter statements using execute immediate

```
begin
   for i in (select table_name from user_tables)
   loop
      execute immediate 'alter table '||i.table_name||' add (newcol varchar2(20))';
  end loop;
end;
/
```